# How to run dynamodb-local in Docker without -inMemory flag

Tags: docker, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-local

According to [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.UsageNotes.html) there are 2 flags that affects run of dynamodb-local

`-inMemory` -> makes all data to persist in RAM only, when service is terminated - all data gets deleted

`-sharedDB` -> makes all logins to be written to the same shared file

no switces -> each credentials login persists data in different file - this is the default behavior

However, if you look in [docker.hub](https://hub.docker.com/layers/amazon/dynamodb-local/latest/images/sha256-7d2178aa20b7a87a05af38cad98b06eedab9dcd4842c8d5290959e4732e63bf2?context=explore) you'll see that the default behavior when running dynamodb-local in docker is with the `-inMemory` flag. but I don't want it, I want the real default behavior.
How can I override it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it was very hard to find it, but it's a very simple solution.

According to this [great post](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/docker-run-override-entrypoint), we can easily override the `[CMD]` part of the docker pulled image.

We just need to add the args after docker run. This is the command that I used:

```
docker run -p 8000:8000 --name local-dynamodb amazon/dynamodb-local -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar
```

`-p` is for defining the port to expose, so your app can contact dynamodb-local on port 8000

`--name` is for giving a readable name to the image

everything after `amazon/dynamodb-local` is the overriding part, the predefined entrypoint is `JAVA`, so we just need to add the `-jar` switch, specify the file name to run, and omit that evil `-inMemory` switch

It’s an option to add a flag `-sharedDb` to make all credentials to connect to the same DB, otherwise - the default is different file for each set of credentials (including region!)

Good luck all! and Happy coding